# BERT: how to batch vectorize efficiently?

Tags: python, word-embedding, bert-language-model

I am trying to convert the sentence into vector using BERT.

```
def bert_embedding(text):
    # text: list of strings(sentences)
    vector = []
    for sentence in tqdm(text):
        e = bert_tokenizer.encode(sentence)
        input = tf.constant(e)[None, :]  # Batch size 1
        output = bert_model(input)
        
        #[CLS] corresponding vector
        vector.append(output[0][0,0,:].numpy())
    return vector
```

I have a text column with around 50k records.

This is very slow. Can we do batch embedding or any efficient method to do this?